# Why didn't I receive all emails after sending them asynchronously in C#?

Tags: c#, email, asynchronous, delegates

I use a specific class to send email asynchronously. You can find the original class [here](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/sending-automated-emails-asynchronously-using-a-c-windows-service-in-conjunction-with-database-email-records-part-i/).

This class uses a delegate function to send emails :

```
public class Email
    {
        public bool SendEmail(MailMessage message)
        {
            try
            {
                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtpClient.Port = 587;
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                ...
                smtpClient.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLogger.SaveLog(ex);
            }
            return true;
        }
        public delegate bool SendEmailDelegate(MailMessage message);

        public void GetResultsOnCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            SendEmailDelegate del = (SendEmailDelegate)((AsyncResult)ar).AsyncDelegate;
            try
            {
               bool result = del.EndInvoke(ar);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLogger.SaveLog(ex);
            }
        }

        public void SendEmailAsync(MailMessage message)
        {
            try
            {
                SendEmailDelegate dc = new SendEmailDelegate(this.SendEmail);
                AsyncCallback cb = new AsyncCallback(this.GetResultsOnCallback);
                IAsyncResult ar = dc.BeginInvoke(message, cb, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLogger.SaveLog(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

But on my website developed in ASP.NET MVC 2, when I try to send 96 emails, only a few of them are received. On my first test, I received 52 emails, and on the second 57 emails.

I have this static class to call the sending emails object

```
public static class EmailSender
{
  private static void SendEmail(MailMessage mail)
  {
     Email sender = new Email();
     sender.SendEmailAsync(mail);
  }

  public static void SendRevival(UserViewModel user){
    ...
    SendEmail(mailMessage);
  }
}
```

And I used it like this:

```
foreach(UserViewModel user in users){
   EmailSender.SendRevival(user);
}
```

There is no error, neither from the application nor from the server.

Does anyone know what's happened ?

Thx.

Comment: Have you looked at the HTTP traffic that comes in/out of your mail server?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your mail server isn't treating them like spam, or rejecting them due to you "flooding" the server with requests?

Comment: Are you leaving the web server instance up long enough to send them all. If you shut down the process, then it will simply stop sending.

Comment: I use googleapps, so gmail to send all my emails. And all received mails are not classified as Spam. @Chris Sainty: the web server instance is managed by IIS, isnt it ? IIS shut down the process after 20 minutes of inactivity. im not sure that im talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking at the return result of your call to

```
sender.SendEmailAsync(mail);
```

to see if the mail was actually sent?

I just looked at the source code for this method and it does this:

```
public bool SendEmailAsync(string toEmail, string toName)
        {
            try
            {
                SendEmailDelegate dc = new SendEmailDelegate(this.SendEmail);
                AsyncCallback cb = new AsyncCallback(this.GetResultsOnCallback);
                IAsyncResult ar = dc.BeginInvoke(toEmail, toName, cb, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

That is, the code is catching any Exception thrown and simply returning false. Not only that but in the AsyncCallback it does the same thing, that is, its 'eating' the Exception and you will never know of any Exceptions.

To Debug your issue I would use the synchronous `SendEmail` call and change his code (in the `SendEmail` method) to **NOT** catch the Exception so the callee (you) knows what happened. eg

```
 private static void SendEmail(MailMessage mail)
 {
     Email sender = new Email();
     sender.SendEmail(mail);//modify this method as well!
 }
```

Comment: I changed the sending object, you can see it in the first message. But i have no error in my log file. With my last try, i received only 34 emails on 96.

Comment: If you send to the SAME email addresses are you getting the same number of received emails each time or does it vary ?

Comment: I send the 96 mails to the same mail address (my gmail address). And i never receive the same number of emails :x